# put :update in rspec not updating attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I am trying to test the **update action** of a devise Model in my app.

My **factories.rb** file:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :student do
    first_name "John"
    last_name "Doe"
    sequence(:email) { |n| "#{first_name}.#{last_name}#{n}@example.com".downcase }
    city "Dhaka"
    area "Mirpur"
    zip 1216
    full_address "Mirpur, Dhaka"
    password "password"
    password_confirmation "password"
    confirmed_at Date.today
  end
end
```

The rspec file:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Students::RegistrationsController do
  context "Student logged in" do
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:student]
      @student = FactoryGirl.create(:student)
      @updated_attributes = { :first_name => "New", :last_name => "Name" }
      sign_in @student
      put :update, :id => @student.id, :student => @updated_attributes

      @student.reload
    end

    it { expect(@student.first_name).to eql "New" }
    it { expect(@student.last_name).to eql "Name" }
  end
end
```

I expected the tests to pass. But they are failing. The failing messages look like this:

> Failure/Error: it { expect(@student.first_name).to eql "New" }
>
> ```
>    expected: "New"
>         got: "John"
>
>    (compared using eql?)
> ```
>
> Failure/Error: it { expect(@student.last_name).to eql "Name" }
>
> ```
>    expected: "Name"
>         got: "Doe"
>
>    (compared using eql?)
> ```

So, basically, the attributes are not getting updated. What do i need to do to make rspec update the attributes and make the tests green?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to include the *:current_password* attribute in the *@updated_attribute* hash. Devise requires you to enter your current password in the edit form. So, *@updated_attribute* should be,

```
@updated_attributes = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:student, :first_name => "New", :last_name => "Name", :current_password => "password" )
```